# Google fusion table Info windows opening slowly in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, google-fusion-tables, google-visualization

I've created a custom Google fusion table-google visualization page, seems to work fine firefox/safari.  However, in IE 8 the info windows open slowly.
here's my link: [link](http://www.anacostia.net/maps/map_search_dev.html).  I'm not sure how to diagnose this problem, or even what specifically to ask. Anyone experience anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just IE 8? I looked at your link in IE 10 and it loaded in the same time as Chrome. While its not IE 8, i tried switching through the modes using the IE developer bar... 7-10 loaded about the same... but i will say i personally have had JQuery/ajax performance issues with IE 7 and 8 (9 and higher seems to have cleared them up). Most of the problems are due to the a more limited support of DOM and HTML standards.. sometimes its just switching some script around... have you been able to time the ajax call (theres some tools out there) vs. rendering time? That might tell you if its your ajax script or if its more related to the HTML rendering.